# IPtables rule to allow Lets encrypt

Tags: iptables

This message appears when I try to get Lets encrypt certificate, because the IPtables rules.
I cannot figure out which rule blocks it, so I want to append "allow" rule. Do you know the right iptables rule command?

```
level=error msg="Unable to obtain ACME certificate for domains \"domain.com\": cannot get ACME client get directory at 'https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory': Get \"https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory\": dial tcp: lookup acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org on 127.0.0.11:53: read udp 127.0.0.1:50147->127.0.0.11:53: i/o timeout" routerName=traefik-secure@docker providerName=letsencrypt.acme rule="Host(`domain.com`)"
```

Comment: how is your server configured to resolve dns queries? are you able to resolve the domain in question from nslookup/dig?

Comment: Hi Frank. It is iptables thing.I just need "allow" rule, because this error. When I disable iptables there is no error, but I get another problem described here: https://superuser.com/questions/1621565/traefik-docker-compose-and-lets-encrypt . The domain points to the server IP due to nslookup.

Comment: look at your dmesg logs. there will be entries describing the traffic that iptables is blocking. it will tell you what source, ports, and protocols you need to allow. try it again, look at the logs, and let us know what they say.

Comment: I have lots of "IPTables Packet Dropped" in dmesg logs.

Comment: yup. youll have to identify the pertinent ones in order to solve your issue. I recommend looking at the log tail to find the starting place, trying the failing process, then looking at the log tail again as quickly as you can, so that you can help narrow it down.

Comment: ok. I tested it with Let's Debug (https://letsdebug.net/) service and I got this error: "domain.com has an A (IPv4) record (IPaddress) but a request to this address over port 80 did not succeed. Experienced error: dial tcp IP:80: connect: connection refused". I got this with or without iptables on. iptables allow input on 80 port. This is VPS server.

Comment: have you verified your HTTP server process is running, and has established a listener on 80? run `netstat -ntlup` and look for port 80. also verify that the local address is not 127.x.y.z. if it is you need to confirgure your webserver to allow external connections. if everything is fine with the service, then your hosting provider probably needs to configure their gateway infrastructure to allow incoming connections on TCP\80 to your server.

Comment: I checked once Traefik docker-compose is up, the 80 and 443 ports are open (listening). While they are open, I checked the error on Letsdebug.net and got error: "context deadline exceeded, Timeout during connect". VPS provider say they do not block anything.

Comment: I try to install Traefik with this manual https://tech.aufomm.com/traefik/ . I modified email for ACME.